# Question about duplicating wp sites with different location every time

Tags: pages, post-duplication

Hello guys i am a novice web developer and i have a question for you!

I have a wordpress page with a text that has some location keywords (e.g. Greece) spread all over it. I want to create multiple pages of the exact same text but with different location every page. Ideally i want to have a .txt file with all the location keywords so the program will read it and create those pages.

How can this be done ?

Thanks for your time !
Have a nice day !